# credit card safety

Tags: credit-card

location: india

While talking to a customer support executive of British airways (number: 1860 180 3592) for payment of extra baggage, he asked for my credit card number, expiry date and cvv number.

I asked him if it will be secure and he said yes. (should i believe him?). Then he proceeded with the transaction and informed that the card was declined with the merchant. I found it odd because i did not get any message from the bank.

now, I am worried if the data will be misused. Any suggestions? should i disable my card and request a new one? or am being paranoid? do CSR of reputed organizations do such things?

thanks

Comment: 1. Did you dial the number or they call you? If they call you, then it is susceptible to calling ID phish, otherwise, it maybe alright.. 2. Credit card exchange and bank may reject transaction from peculiar source, i.e. merchant that you never do transaction with, or merchant that have many fraud dispute.  3. It is up to individual bank to implement credit card anti-fraud verification.   In short, call the bank to verify the activities, if there is no activity recorded, then you should cancel your card.

Comment: 1. I initiated the call. the CSR seems legit. he changed some other things in booking for me. just worried about CC information 2. I have raised a complaint with British Airways asking them if this is normal. will update if any news comes up.

Comment: Some merchant use a dial-tone verification process, i.e. the operator will transfer you to a process required you to dial the CVV number in your phone, which actually cut away from the operator. In such case, there is no way the CSR personnel able to record down the number if the CSR services is legit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> now, I am worried if the data will be misused. Any suggestions? should i disable my card and request a new one? or am being paranoid? do CSR of reputed organizations do such things?

The first thing you should do is call your bank and ask them about the rejection.  If the CSR legitimately tried to run the card and had it declined, they can see that and tell you why - and if they *can't* find any record of it, you can cancel the card right then... but you still may not have to.

There's obviously no way to be sure that the rep didn't write down your card information for his personal use later, but any company that does MOTO (Mail Order/Telephone Order) transactions will have policies and procedures to prevent it, because it's a known risk to their business.  It doesn't mean it can't happen, but asking for this information is not immediate cause for suspicion.  [This reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/3mdcth/eli5_how_do_they_stop_people_at_call_centers_from/) mentions some examples of the kinds of precautions a reputable business can take to prevent this kind of thing from happening.

Additionally, even if the rep were to write down your information, why would they fake a decline from your bank?  Better to write it down, let the transaction go through to ensure that *you're* giving *them* legitimate card information, and only **then** go off to use it fraudulently.

All-in-all, **confirm with your bank, but you're probably safe.**

Comment: I checked with the bank. there was indeed a request from BA which was declined by the bank. However with the security breach in BA and stuff, the card blocking proved to be ok after all... As Bobson mentioned in bold: Always Confirm with the bank!!!

Answer (score -2):

If you tell someone your credit card information over the phone you don't know where they're putting it. They could be already making fraudulent purchases on your card or anything else in that region. Make sure you change your credit card number ASAP!

Comment: Giving card information over the phone is a relatively normal thing to do.  While it's true that you don't know what they're doing with it, the same thing applies to *any* form of ecommerce transaction.

Comment: There are PCI DSS compliance guidelines.
https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/protecting_telephone-based_payment_card_data.pdf

Comment: A CSR that make use of dial-tone verification will prevent human from copy down the card number and CVV